# Do any Jewish commentators or any targum or midrash see Haggai 2:7 as a reference to the messiah?

Tags: hebrew, tanach, rabbis, messiah, book-of-haggai

Haggai 2:7 speaks about the coming of "the desired of nations". Christians say this is a reference to the messiah. But I'm wondering if any of the sages - the commentaries or targum or midrash agreed and saw it as a reference to the coming of the messiah? Can you please check? The only possible reference I know is Sanhedrin 97.

Comment: I don't understand why it would refer to the messiah: In the Hebrew [the verse](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&lang2=en) says "**וּבָאוּ** חֶמְדַּת כָּל הַגּוֹיִם", in plural. If it refers to the messiah, shouldn't it have said "**וּבָא** חֶמְדַּת כָּל הַגּוֹיִם", in singular?

Comment: @TamirEvan now go try explain that to Christians. Probably won't work...

Comment: @TamirEvan Yah the thing is the verb is plural but the subject is singular. So if it was referring to wealth- wealth shouldve been in the plural. But if referring to messiah- the verb shouldve been singular. There may be a scribal error here or an error with the vowels.

Comment: @Moon For me there is a better possibility: the verse is what's called a "[מקרא קצר](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%A8&tab=text&tvar=0&svar=1)" (an elliptical verse, like [Rashi says about "וימלא אחרי", "he hath filled after Me", in Numbers 14:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.14.24?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.14.24.2&lang2=bi)), and means "וּבָאוּ [אלו שהם] חֶמְדַּת כָּל הַגּוֹיִם" ("and came [those/them that are] the desired of nations"). I don't need to resort here to claims of scribal/vowelization errors.

Answer (score 3):

None that I can see (not [Targum Yonatan](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Haggai&lang2=en), [Tanchuma](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Midrash%20Tanchuma&lang2=en), [Tanchuma Buber](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Midrash%20Tanchuma%20Buber&lang2=en), [Otzar Hamidrashim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Otzar%20Midrashim&lang2=en), [Shemot Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Shemot%20Rabbah&lang2=en), or the following commentators: [Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en), [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en), [Metzudat David](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en), [Metzudat Tzion](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20Zion&lang2=en), [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.7?lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en) and [Hoil Moshe](https://media.alhatorah.org/Parshanim/Hoil%20Moshe/Terei%20Asar%20Commentary.pdf)). They all say it refers to physical wealth (gold, silver, riches, etc).

Edit: The commentary of the student of the [RI"D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_di_Trani) (can be found [here](https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/1/1)) says that it refers to the armies of Gog and Magog.

[Rabbi Yosef Kara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Kara) (see the link before the previous one) says it refers to the Land of Israel.